# Polynormal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. $H$ is said to be polynormal in $G$ if for each $x\in G$, we have $H^{\langle x \rangle} = H^{H^{\langle x \rangle}}$ where $H^{\langle x \rangle} = \langle x^nHx^{-n} \;|\; n\in \mathbb{Z}\rangle$

I just saw this group property now in a journal paper and one of the characterisations is that:

A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is polynormal $\iff $ $H^K = H^L$ for any subgroups $K$ and $L$ such that $H\leq K \unlhd L\leq G$.

The proof of this proposition appears in a Russian journal which I do not have access to and I'm not sure how to prove this

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is polynormal and $H \le K \unlhd L$ then, for $l \in L$,
$H^l \le H^{\langle l \rangle} = H^{H^{\langle l \rangle}} \le H^K$.

Conversely, $H^{\langle x \rangle} \unlhd \langle H,x \rangle$ so,
assuming the condition,
$H^{H^{x}} = H^{\langle H,x \rangle} = H^{\langle x \rangle}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm just having a problem with the last equality $H^{\langle H, x \rangle} = H^{\langle x \rangle}$

Comment: I managed to show that $H^{\langle x \rangle} \leq H^{\langle H, x\rangle}$. I'm not sure how the other inclusion follows

Comment: To show that $H^{\langle H,x \rangle} \le H^{\langle x \rangle}$ it is sufficient to show that both $H$ and $x$ lie in the normalizer of $H^{\langle x \rangle}$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply due to my internet being down for the past two days. Why would it suffice to show that result? Clearly $H \leq H^{\langle x\rangle} \leq N_G(H^{\langle x\rangle})$ and $xH^{\langle x \rangle}x^{-1} = H^{\langle x \rangle}$ thus $x \in N_G(H^{\langle  x \rangle})$

Comment: If $H$ and $x$ normalize $H^{\langle x \rangle}$ then so does $\langle H,x \rangle$ and hence $H^{\langle H,x \rangle} \le (H^{\langle x \rangle})^{\langle H,x \rangle} = H^{\langle x \rangle}$.